# Oracle update one table in relation to entering data into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

the scenario is simple

```
CREATE TABLE one
(ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT
pk_id PRIMARY KEY,
Number_of_relations INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE two
(mock_id NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (mock_id) REFERENCES one(ID)
text VARCHAR)
```

is it possible to update Number_of_relations every time you enter a new row into table two. so if i enter ID in table one as '1', at the moment Number_of_relations is at '0', but if i add ('1', 'hello') and ('1', 'helloagain') into table two, now id '1' has two texts to it, but i want the number_of_relations to update (automatically if possible) in table one to '2'. is it possible?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger does it:

```
create or replace trigger ins_two after insert on two
for each row
  update one set number_of_relations = number_of_relations + 1
    where one.id = :new.mock_id
```

Test:

```
insert into two values (1, 'hello');
insert into two values (1, 'hello again');
insert into two values (2, 'hello');

select * from one

        ID NUMBER_OF_RELATIONS
---------- -------------------
         1                   2 
         2                   1
```

This is example for INSERT action, you can add also sections for DELETE and UPDATE. 
In "DELETE" case number_of_relations has to be decremented, 
in "UPDATE" - it depends what column was updated, but logic is similar.
[Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) documentation and examples.